# TxTextControl Load a Image into document Dotnet

Tags: asp.net, .net, txtextcontrol

I am new to TXTextControl. I am currently using TXTextControl 24 version.

I need to upload an image from local system (Client system) into the document.

I have written the JS for uploading the file through .

The JS makes a call to backend service which gets the file, Add it to a new RTF file and respond back to JS. The RTF file is then loaded to the Selection.Load of TextControl.

Code: add image to RTF

```
TXTextControl.ServerTextControl tx = new TXTextControl.ServerTextControl();
tx.Create();
tx.Images.Add(myImage, tx.InputPosition.Page, new Point(100, 100), TXTextControl.ImageInsertionMode.FixedOnPage);
string sHTML;
tx.Save(out sHTML, TXTextControl.StringStreamType.RichTextFormat);
```

The server responds back with with message "The Module for displaying image is obsolete. (01-0803)"

How can I add the Image into the TXTextControl Document ?

Comment: Did you manage to get a resolution for this issue?

Comment: Have you found any solution I am using TX Text Control.NET for Windows Forms 21.0 and i have the same problem

Comment: we are getting same error. have you found any solutions? Need help here urgently Please

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to replicate this error message in a slightly different context, and this is what worked for me.

My context: I'm embedding TXTextControl (v29) in a .Net (Framework) app. Redistribution size is important, so I'm minimising the number of embedded DLLs to reduce footprint. I know that I will only ever be processing RTF -> PDF documents, so I'm bundling *just* these files inside my app (leaving out the DLLs for `xls` etc handling).

Embedded runtime DLL files:

```
tx29_pdf.dll
tx29_rtf.dll
TXImageProvider.dll
txkernel.dll
txpdf.dll
TXTextControl.dll
TXTextControl.Server.dll
```

My internal app calling code looks like this:

```
var serverTextControl1 = new TXTextControl.ServerTextControl();
serverTextControl1.Create();

serverTextControl1.Load(inputFilename, TXTextControl.StreamType.RichTextFormat);
serverTextControl1.Save(outputFilename, TXTextControl.StreamType.AdobePDF);
```

Which works just fine, when processing plaintext RTF files. Also, this "works on my machine" for any/all test suite files (also works on any machine that has the full TXTextControl installation performed - my app can clearly find the correct DLLs at runtime in the .Net GAC and/or via Registry registration).

However, shipping (just) the binaries in the list above to a new server and then processing RTF files is a different matter (for full clarity: this is using the  embedded-licence option, as documented on the TXTextControl website, where my licence key is embedded into my `Program.cs`-derived compiled binary).

Processing general plaintext RTF -> PDF files works fine on a new server, but when processing RTFs with *linked* images in the document, my app fails; there is a DLL or two missing from the above list!

Error message is:

```
Unhandled Exception: TXTextControl.TextEditorException: The module for displaying images is obsolete.
(01-0803)
   at TXTextControl.LoadSettings.?(String , StreamType , TextControlCore , ? , DocumentSettings )
   at TXTextControl.ServerTextControl.Load(String path, StreamType streamType)
   at RTFToPDFConsole.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\...\TXTextControl\Program.cs:line 24
```

I have fixed this by adding in two more DLLs from the TXTControl `bin` distribution:

```
msvcp120.dll
txic.dll
```

Now my app works again!